# How are yum packages classified as security related during check-update?

Tags: linux, yum

Running `yum --security check-update` will give security related updates. How does it classify security related update, who gives that classification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoever maintains the package repository tags a package as a security update when they add it to the repository.